# How to customise the activities status?

Tags: activities, best-practice

I'd like to remove some statues (ie. Left message), and add some more (to support our workflow.

I could add another "status" custom field, but I'd much prefer customise the existing one rather than create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

From the administer dashboard, you can modify the option groups:

civicrm/admin/options?reset=1

and the activity status is one of them (/civicrm/admin/options?gid=26&reset=1 in my case).

However, there is a big

```
 WARNING: Many option groups are used programatically and values should be added or modified with caution.
```

- Left Message
- Unreachable
- Available
- No-show

Are not reserved (ie. we can delete them)

Is this safe to do so? can I add new statues without issue?

Answer (score 1):

I almost never delete those options, but use the disable option instead, then they can be re-enabled easily. Some code might be counting on those particular id's that ship with CiviCRM (bad, but happens ...). Re-enabling is easy, and then they keep their old id's.

Comment: Cool, and you have disabled them and no major issue then?

Answer (score 0):

I would test Xavier, but I think it is save to delete those. The only one where I would have a question mark is with the No-show, that might be used by Events?

Comment: hey, the problem is how to test: it might be weeks and months before I need to organise an event where whatever is happening and it ends up needing the No-show status. and even then, it might just silently discard something and I will never notice that the status is actually useful;)

Comment: Agreed :-) But it might be possible to do a quick test on demo and set a participant status to a no-show and see what the auto-generated activity (i assume there is one) shows? That is the only spot I would reckon something with that status might happen.

Comment: And the silent discarding goes for a lot of things that we never notice until it hurts :-)

Comment: I never delete the options for activity status, I disable just like Erik would. I guess the code will use the statuses for different modules such as CiviEvent, but there is no easy way to test this out